# JavaScript functions from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

quick question.

I have an array with 3 functions. When I call the specific function I want to perform it does not respond to the specific index within the array. It just performs all functions till it gets to the last function.

Here is the code:

```
<p id="sometext">Change Color</p>
<script>
    function paintRed() {
        var text = document.getElementById('sometext');
        text.style.color = "red";
    }

    function paintBlue() {
        var text = document.getElementById('sometext');
        text.style.color = "blue";

    }
    function paintYellow() {
        var text = document.getElementById('sometext');
        text.style.color = "yellow";

    }

    var arrcolor = [ paintRed(), paintBlue(), paintYellow()];

    arrcolor[0]; //This returns the yellow color and not red//

</script>
```

So my

Change Color

always returns as yellow (The last function in the array) regardless of which index I call i.e (arrcolor[0],arrcolor[1]).

Hope it makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shoud add the functions to the array, instead of calling them, like so:

```
var arrcolor = [ paintRed, paintBlue, paintYellow ];
```

Later, you can call each of them:

```
arrcolor[0]();
```

Don't forget the final `()`, as you're calling a function.

Answer (score 5):

You can only put the function name (actually, reference) in the array and execute it like this

```
var arrcolor = [ paintRed, paintBlue, paintYellow];

arrcolor[2]();
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/93p4fhtp/)

An alternative way of doing same is creating an object and put each of the function inside it

```
var changeColor = {
  paintRed :function(text){
     text.style.color = "red";
   },

   paintBlue :function(text){
     text.style.color = "blue";
   },
   paintYellow:function(text){
       text.style.color = "yellow";
    }

}
var text = document.getElementById('sometext');
changeColor.paintRed(text)
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/93p4fhtp/1/)

Comment: I'm not going to get into an edit war here.  It's a reference, and by calling it that, you might educate somebody (or is it you that needs the educating?)

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I think I updated my answer . You have liberty edit if it is necessary also I don't know which war you are talking about

Answer (score 1):

I think it should read like this:

```
<p id="sometext">Change Color</p>
<script>
    function paintRed() {
        var text = document.getElementById('sometext');
        text.style.color = "red";
    }

    function paintBlue() {
        var text = document.getElementById('sometext');
        text.style.color = "blue";

    }
    function paintYellow() {
        var text = document.getElementById('sometext');
        text.style.color = "yellow";

    }

    var arrcolor = [ paintRed, paintBlue, paintYellow];

    arrcolor[0]();

</script>
```

Description: array stores only a function reference and when you dereference it, then it will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets following the function names `var arrcolor = [ paintRed(), paintBlue(), paintYellow()]`.

You have already called the functions when you declare and initialise `arrcolor`, therefore it will be storing the return values from the functions, which in this case will give `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`.

Answer (score 0):

is that because you execute each function in array, but last one is `paintYellow()`

look:

```
var arrcolor = [ paintRed(), paintBlue(), paintYellow()];
```

now your arrcolor has 3 elements which are "undefined", because each of your function doesn't return any data (you can check it - `typeof(arrcolor[0]) == "undefined"`). If you want to call first element you should define your array as "pointers of functions", like that:

```
var arrcolor = [ paintRed, paintBlue, paintYellow];
```

and then execute your selected `paintRed`:

```
arrcolor[0]();
```